# Why is my Apache Spark job slower than regular Python program?

Tags: python, parallel-processing, apache-spark

It's just a simple program which counts number of lines in a log file. The log file is about 6GB. I ran two programs like below:

**Regular Python program**

```
import datetime

begining = datetime.datetime.now()
if __name__ == "__main__":
    num_lines = sum(1 for line in open('/Users/victor/access.log'))
    print "The file contains of %s lines" % num_lines
    ending = datetime.datetime.now()
    print "processed in: %s" % (ending - begining)
```

**Spark version using Python**

```
import sys
from operator import add
from pyspark import SparkContext

if __name__ == "__main__":
    sc = SparkContext(appName="PythonAccessLogAnalyzer")
    lines = sc.textFile("/Users/victor/access.log")
    # count number of line
    counts = lines.count()
    print "The file contains of %s lines" % counts

    sc.stop()
```

Because spark is for parallel processing, I think it should be faster than the regular python program. However, after I ran spark version with 4 processing cores, it took almost *45s* to complete the task while the regular program just needed *8s*. **Why? How can I improve the Spark version to make it faster than the regular one?**

As I know, Spark splits the files into many chunks and processes them in parallel but still need some time to initialize jobs. In this case, that time from initializing jobs are too big in comparison to the regular python program processing time (mostly on loading the file). If I'm correct, **what is size of the file where Spark version is superior to the regular one?**

Comment: This is not a real answer for your generic question, but in your case the task is strictly IO-bound. This means that the first program will always operate at the speed of your disk drive, whereas parallel program will require both disk operations and the communication overhead (things like transmitting data over the network, which might be slower than local disk access). You need a more complex problem to actually start seeing benefits of parallel processing.

Comment: @liori, actually you answered my "Why?" question. Thank you. Any suggestion on complex problem so I can start my experiments?

Comment: How are you running Spark? (local mode)?

Comment: Yes. I ran it locally on my Mac. I ran it with 4 processing cores.